# Data augmentation with GAN Network for handwriting alphabets recognition

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, handwriting-recognition, generative-adversarial-network

I have a short dataset for recognizing Bengali alphabets (`9600` data for training and `3000` for testing).
The total number of classes: `50`.

This seems to be a short number of data.
So I was trying to augment the data set by `ImageDataGenerator` from `keras.preprocessing.image`. It was working well.

Now I'm trying to augment data by `GAN network` to generate a larger dataset.

I've read some basics and followed some tutorials. Like [this one](https://deeplearning4j.org/generative-adversarial-network) from deeplearning4j.org and followed this [code](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py) from Github.

But I am at a loss how to generate the augmented data.

Maybe, I am missing some strategies. Can someone please tell me the strategies for generating data with GAN?

My Strategy was:

1. Preparing `training` and `test` dataset.
2. Training the `Generator` and `discriminator`.
3. Generating new image by `Generator`
4. Trying to discriminate between the `real` and `fake` image

After 100 epochs I got:
[image]

Comment: So where exactly are you getting stuck?
Your approach to GANs seems reasonable, and should work for you. I want to point out that the number of pictures might be a little low for training a GAN, but should generally still work.

Comment: First of all to generate new data with gan.
I tried with the code (linked in the question) with my dataset. and can generate only some noise only.

Comment: Can you edit your post to contain maybe a sample image of your generated output, how many epochs you left the training running, whether you see constant improvement, etc.?
Also, the code you linked is seemingly a stack of "regular" hidden layers (i.e. fully connected layers), from what I know about Keras. For the case of images you can get much better results by using a [DCGAN](https://github.com/jacobgil/keras-dcgan) (Deep Convolutional GAN), which simply replaces the architectures with regular convolutions/deconvolutions. That should also improve your results significantly.

Comment: Also the loss function defined in the code example you gave does not make any sense. Generally, to get a decent training curve, you have to flip the loss when it comes to training the generator (which is more what you want anyways). The theory behind that is explained well [here](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/09/17/gan-tensorflow/).

Comment: Ok, I am posting my full code. And maybe I should give a try with you DCGAN code.

Comment: Can I use [this Keras Implementation code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_acgan.py) by changing the data set?